# mysql LEFT JOIN select query with limited results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I am facing a situation and need help. I have two tables:

**user:**

- `user_id`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`.

**user_timesheet:**

- `time_id`, `user_id`, `month`, `state`, `date`.

Users are to add time to `user_time` table with the state as = 'no' and at the end of the month they submit that time which change the state = 'yes' assuming the month is JUNE
I want to write a query that will bring all users who did not add time at all and users who have added time but has not submit for JUNE.

This is my query.

```
SELECT user_timesheet.time_id, user_timesheet.user_id, 
    user_timesheet.month, user_timesheet.`state`, 
    `user`.user_id, `user`.fname, `user`.lname,  
    `user`.email
FROM user LEFT JOIN  
     user_timesheet ON user.user_id=user_timesheet.user_id
WHERE (
    user_timesheet.state = 'no' OR 
    user_timesheet.state IS NULL) 
AND (
    user_timesheet.month = 'june' OR 
    user_timesheet.month IS NULL)
GROUP BY user.user_id
```

The result bring all users who have added time in june but have submitted it and also the users who have NEVER ADDED TIME to the system since they join. It however does not bring users who have either added time or submitted time in the previous month but has not added time at all for june.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of (a = x or a is null) in where clause put your filter in ON clause. This will remove non-matching records but preserve nature of left join.

To treat 'no' status as non existant row filter it out of left join:

```
SELECT user_timesheet.time_id, user_timesheet.user_id, 
       user_timesheet.month, user_timesheet.`state`, 
       `user`.user_id, `user`.fname, `user`.lname,  
       `user`.email
  FROM user 
  LEFT JOIN user_timesheet
  -- Eliminate users who have submitted 'no'
  -- For June
    ON user.user_id=user_timesheet.user_id
    -- Turn 'no' status into null record
   AND user_timesheet.state <> 'no'
   AND user_timesheet.month = 'june'
  -- If there is no row in user_timesheet
  -- It means that
  --    a) There was not any
  --    b) There was a 'no' status
 WHERE user_timesheet.user_id is null
 GROUP BY user.user_id
```

Note: I don't know what is comment marker in MySql. It is -- in Sql Server, so delete this lines before you try the query.

Comment: thank you very much. please if i might ask, what does this <> means in the statement

Comment: @user1451414 <> means `not equal` in standard sql. You are welcome :-)

Comment: @user1451414 Functionally, none whatsoever. But when presented with a choice between proprietary and standard syntax of same value, I choose standard. Eases a life a bit when you have to switch DB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all start by creating a query that match the userId of all the user that added time in the specified period with the "YES" state => you have all the "good" users. then you juste have to select all the user that are not in that list. You could use a not in, a not exists with a sub query or a minus query.

example with not in :

```
SELECT user_timesheet.time_id, user_timesheet.user_id, user_timesheet.month, user_timesheet.`state`, `user`.user_id, `user`.fname, `user`.lname,  `user`.email
  FROM user LEFT JOIN user_timesheet ON user.user_id=user_timesheet.user_id
where user.user_id not in (
  select user.user_id 
    from user inner join user_timesheet ON user.user_id=user_timesheet.user_id 
  where user_timesheet.state = 'yes' 
  AND user_timesheet.month = june
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_timesheet.time_id, user_timesheet.user_id, user_timesheet.month, user_timesheet.`state`, 
       `user`.user_id, `user`.fname, `user`.lname, `user`.email
  FROM user 
  LEFT JOIN user_timesheet
    ON user.user_id=user_timesheet.user_id
    AND user_timesheet.month = 'june' AND user_timesheet.state = 'no'
```

Comment: AND user_timesheet.month = 'june' AND user_timesheet.state = 'no'             will make sure that the month is june and not submitted since no denotes no time submitted till the end of month.